# USB PPD Printer (Sharp AR-M160) does not show up on OSX 10.10

Tags: macos, usb, printing, printer, multi-function-printer

I have an old Sharp AR-M160 Multi Functional Printer and I want to get it to work on OSX 10.10 Yosemite.
[Here](http://www.sharp.com.hk/html/eng/downloads/ListingDriver?productDownload_id=0&model=AR-M160&modelno=&x=51&y=8) they offer PPD-Drivers for 10.4 which I suppose should be fine and installed.

I checked and they are in `/Library/Printers/PPDs/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/`. Also the printer shows up in the USB Section of the System Information as `AR-M160/AR-EB7`.
But if I want to add a printer over the System Settings nothing shows up.

Am I missing something or is the trial of getting this thing to run futile?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried browsing to the printer in the en.lproj folder when you install it?

Also, as it is a PostSCript printer, all you really need is the PPD file. This is a text file, so you can get one from any driver, OS10, Windows or Linux. Just install it in the lproj folder and browse to it during installation.

Comment: The problem is that there is no "installation process". The Add Printer ([as seen as here](https://support.apple.com/library/content/dam/edam/applecare/images/en_US/osx/add_printer_ss.png)) window does not list any printer.